# Compile error on Anchor 0.27 when using anchor-spl

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang

I am using the following Anchor dependencies:

```
anchor-lang = "0.27.0"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.27.0", features = ["metadata"] }
```

But it breaks when compiling because seems like the `create_metadata_accounts_v2` function doesn't exist anymore within the `mpl_token_metadata` library:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `create_metadata_accounts_v2` in module `mpl_token_metadata::instruction`
   --> src/metadata.rs:24:47
    |
24  |       let ix = mpl_token_metadata::instruction::create_metadata_accounts_v2(
    |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `create_metadata_accounts_v3`
```

I am just using it to obtain the token metadata:

```
use anchor_spl::metadata::MetadataAccount;

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Allowed<'info> {
   #[account()]
   pub signer: Signer<'info>,
   ...
   ...
   #[account(
       seeds = [b"metadata", mpl_token_metadata::ID.as_ref(), metadata.mint.key().as_ref()],
       seeds::program = mpl_token_metadata::ID,
       constraint = metadata.mint == token.as_ref().unwrap().mint @ Unauthorized,
       bump,
   )]
   pub metadata: Option<Account<'info, MetadataAccount>>,
}
```

Does somebody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `mpl-token-metadata` using `"=1.9.0"` within your `Cargo.toml` dependencies, E.G:

```
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.27.0"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.27.0", features = ["metadata"] }
mpl-token-metadata = { version = "=1.9.0", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `create_metadata_accounts_v3` instead.
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/spl/src/metadata.rs#L98

`create_metadata_accounts_v2` will be removed in the next anchor release.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking

Comment: Well yeah, but how can I do that if that is [actually part of anchor-spl v0.27.0](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/v0.27.0/spl/src/metadata.rs#L24) itself. I cannot get rid of that error unless I wait to Anchor 0.28.0?

Comment: I mean `create_metadata_accounts_v3` already supported in anchor 0.27.0